# Convert Long to Integer

Tags: java, android, youtube

I use a YoutubePlaylist-Master library on Github for my android app.
I want have only the last video of the channel, i've try to modify the code but i have a problem :

When i set the value to 1, i've an error because i use Interger and not a Long.

```
public abstract class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, List<Video>>> {
    private static final String TAG = "GetPlaylistAsyncTask";
    private static final Long YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 1L;
    private static final Integer YOUTUBE_LAST_V = 1;

    //see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
    private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART = "snippet";
    private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS = "pageInfo,nextPageToken,items(id,snippet(resourceId/videoId))";
    //see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
    private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART = "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"; // video resource properties that the response will include.
    private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS = "items(id,snippet(title,description,thumbnails/high),contentDetails/duration,statistics)"; // selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.

        (...)

    @Override
    protected Pair<String, List<Video>> doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String playlistId = params[0];
        final String nextPageToken;

        if (params.length == 2) {
            nextPageToken = params[1];
        } else {
            nextPageToken = null;
        }

        PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse;
        try {
            playlistItemListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.playlistItems()
                    .list(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART)
                    .setPlaylistId(playlistId)
                    .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                    .setFields(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS)
                    .setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS)
                    .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (playlistItemListResponse == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get playlist");
            return null;
        }

        List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList();

        // pull out the video id's from the playlist page
        for (PlaylistItem item : playlistItemListResponse.getItems()) {
            videoIds.add(item.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId());
        }

        // get details of the videos on this playlist page
        VideoListResponse videoListResponse = null;
        try {
            videoListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.videos()
                    .list(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART)
                    .setFields(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS)
                    .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                    .setId(TextUtils.join(",", videoIds)).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Pair(playlistItemListResponse.getNextPageToken(), videoListResponse.getItems());
    }
}
```

So the problem is :

I have 2 VAR :

```
private static final Long YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 1L;

private static final Integer YOUTUBE_LAST_V = 1;
```

In `protected Pair<String, List<Video>> doInBackground(String... params)` class when i try to change `.setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS)` to `.setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_LAST_V)`, i've the error : `Error:(70, 36) error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Long`

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the error is, we cannot help you.  Sorry.

Comment: I've edited my post (at the end)

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxResults()` does not accept `int` type data, so change `YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS` type to `long` (suffix `L`) as shown below:

```
private static final Long YOUTUBE_LAST_V = 1L;
```

Comment: `setMaxResults()` accept only `long` type data, i've try to change `YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS` to `YOUTUBE_LAST_V` but i've `Error:(70, 36) error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Long`

Comment: You need to use `Long YOUTUBE_LAST_V = 1L`, check above

Comment: Can we "force" int data ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set

```
private static final Integer YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 1;
```

It's a static final field, - so it's never changed and `Integer` is sufficient...

Comment: Yes, i'v try this but when i compile i've an error : `Error:(70, 36) error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Long`

Comment: As shown in the API, you cannot call this method with an `Integer` parameter. 

`YouTube.PlaylistItems.List  setMaxResults(java.lang.Long maxResults)
The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set.`

Why do you need an integer value as argument?